# Append contents of .txt file in bash variable

Tags: bash, variables

I have a .txt file which has the following form content-wise:

```
1003
1004
1005
1006
.
.
.
and so on
```

These numbers are indexes to folder paths. e.g

```
/Users/My_user/1003/files/
/Users/My_user/1004/files/
and so on
```

I want to assign each path of the different ones to a bash variable like:

```
var = '/Users/My_user/1003/files/ /Users/My_user/1004/files/ /Users/My_user/1005/files/ (and so on)'
```

Till now i have tried something like this:

```
for index in $(cat the_text.txt);
do
var = '/Users/My_user/$index/files'
done
```

But of course it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: It is a bit unclear what your final goal is. Do you want to store all this info in a variable or have the variable contain a specific path on every step of the loop?

Comment: i want the variable to contain all the paths next to each other exactly in the form I wrote above. If, of course, something like this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append values to your variable:

```
for index in $(cat the_text.txt);
do
var="${var:+$var }/Users/My_user/$index/files"
done
```

**PS**. `var="${var:+$var }"` will avoid leading space

Answer (score 4):

Put them into an array:

```
DIRPATHS=();
while read -r index;
do
   DIRPATHS+=("/Users/My_user/$index/files/");
done < indices.txt
```

*You can read from a file without calling an external program (`cat`) in Bash.*

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you for your reminder on formatting. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In bash, this can be done without a loop at all:

```
$ cat the_text.txt
1003
1004
1005
1006
$ prefix="/Users/my_user/"
$ suffix="/files/"
$ mapfile -t var < the_text.txt
$ var=( "${var[@]/#/$prefix}" )
$ var=( "${var[@]/%/$suffix}" )
$ printf "%s\n" "${var[@]}"
/Users/my_user/1003/files/
/Users/my_user/1004/files/
/Users/my_user/1005/files/
/Users/my_user/1006/files/
```

Then if you want one space-separated string:

```
all_dirs=${var[*]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would changing the line in your `for` loop to `var="$var /Users/My_user/$index/files"` work?

Comment: Not with single quotes

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for pointing that out. Nice solution on your part too.